# Django localization in asynchronously sent emails and notifications

Tags: django, asynchronous, internationalization

I have a django project that makes use of [django-celery-beat](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat) and [redis](https://redis.io/) to make use of asynchronous messages. This is especially useful for handling sending many emails (for example, if an admin clicks a button, hundreds of emails have to be sent, without using celery/redis, this would take quite some time).

It's almost the same for browser-notifications. I have set up a few cron tasks that fire notifications to useres depending on various variables.

This all works fine, however, I am unable to find an elegant way for localizing the emails/notifications.

I am somewhat familiar with how internationalization works within django, and for localizing direct responses and error messages, I am sending the `accept-language` flag (based on the current browser language) from my (angular) frontend. Django respects this (according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)) and this is working fine.

However, when dealing with async tasks, there is no such thing as a request where django can look for a preferred language. When sending emails, I could pass the language from the `accept-language` field on to my async function, by setting the language within my function manually for each user ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)).

This wont work for notifications, as they are sent by a cron job, so there is no response where I could get the preferred language to begin with.

The only idea I could come up with is adding a `language` field to my `User` model. Upon registration (or by some other logic), this field is set to the preferred lanuage, and from within my async function, I can determine the target language from that field. However, that seems not to be too elegant, and I was wondering if there is anything that I am missing.

Is there really no other way for that?